# Getting Widget properties

Tags: kentico

How can I get widget properties given that I know the URL, language and version I want of a page. I am trying to get a property of a widget instance from a completely different project in the same solution. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using MVC or Portal Engine?

Answer (score 0):

Incase some one needs it in future. I think I have figured it out now. Remember to resolve the url before use.

```
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider();
TreeNode staticNode = tree.SelectSingleNode(siteName, url, culture);
PageInfo pi = CMSWebPartPropertiesPage.GetPageInfo(staticNode.NodeAliasPath, staticNode.DocumentPageTemplateID, culture);
PageTemplateInstance templateInstance = pi.DocumentTemplateInstance;
WebPartInstance widgetInstance = templateInstance.GetWebPart(widgetName);
```